# Detecting USB footpedal button presses

Tags: c#, windows, usb

I need to create a Windows app or service which is capable of detecting a USB footpedal button click, but I am not sure where to start. Any pointers?

Tried to google to start with but have failed to make much progress.

It is a [Philips foot pedal](https://www.dictation.philips.com/us/products/transcription-accessories/foot-control-lfh2300/) connected via USB to a Windows 10 computer. I know how to code in C#, just need some help to get started on how to actually detect the footpedal button clicks.

Comment: For starters, I imagine *which* foot pedal is necessary information. Also it's entirely likely that it's speaking some proprietary language to a Philips driver, which has its own undocumented API

Comment: [This SDK looks promising](https://www.dictation.philips.com/tr/products/workflow-software/sdk-for-speechexec-recorder-and-dictation-hardware-lfh7440/). Based on the description, I would imagine that you're unlikely to get a license as a solo developer

Comment: @canton7, is some sort of reverse engineering not possible with SetWindowsHookEx to capture the correct value being passed to the computer when anything is clicked, keyboard, mouse, footpedal?

Comment: If you've set up the Philips software to turn pedal presses into things like mouse or keyboard events, yes you can probably pick those up with a hook. But it's highly unlikely that you'll be able to hook directly into the pedal.

Comment: The one I have acts like a keyboard which will pass on key codes for, I think 'a'. 'b'  and  'c' much like a barcode scanner..

Comment: @TaW, which one do you have and were you able to capture the key codes using a programming language such as C#?